# Sorting and merging two arrays in efficient way?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

We have two arrays (not sorted), of capacity **n** and **n+m**. The first array has **n** elements. The second array has **m** elements (and additionally **n** places reserved for more elements).

The goal is to merge the two arrays and store the result in the second array in a sorted manner, without using extra space.

Currently, I sort both arrays using quick-sort and then merge them using merge-sort. Is there a more efficient way to achieve this???

Comment: If this is homework that's fine, but you should say so. What have you tried so far?

Comment: What is the size of the second array? `n` or `n+m` and what have you tried till now?

Comment: @Thrustmaster Size n+m, contains m elements.

Comment: Sorted both my arrays using quick sort and then merged using MergeSort

Comment: @Pixel so what was the problem with that approach? Update your question to state what you've tried, and what you want help with.

Comment: @Sepster Is my approach is the efficient way of approaching this problem ?

Comment: You tried two different things. Which approach do you mean "is efficient."  It depends on your input, etc... If it's sorted, quicksort will be slow. If it is a low number of items quicksort will be slow...  Otherwise either of these will provide similar average case scenarios, but a possible O(n^2) worst case time for quicksort)

Comment: If you are storing in a second array, than you are using extra space.

Comment: @CarlosHenriqueRodriguez No, my defined size of 2nd array is n+m, so i am not using any extra space

Comment: @Pixel yes, you are, by doing this you will have 3 arrays, n, m and n+m

Comment: @Sepster [The homework tag is deprecated.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated)

Comment: @brimborium Yes it is.  But that doesn't mean it's not good practice to admit the question is homework in an effort to garner more complete/explanatory answers http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/10812#10812

Comment: @Sepster You are right, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2):

You can explore merge sort.

https://www.google.com/search?q=mergesort&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en&client=safari#itp=open0

Or depending on the size, you can do quicksort on each array, and then merge them using the merge sort technique (or merge, then quicksort).

I would go with mergesort, it basically works by sorting each array individually, then it puts them together in order

You're looking at O(nlogn) for mergesort and O(nlogn) for quicksort, but possible O(n^2) worst case with quicksort.

Comment: Merge sort can also be implemented as a stable algorithm so you can maintain relative order. Quicksort won't do that

Comment: mergesort requires O(n) extra space

Comment: Then use quicksort. Alternatively use an AVL tree as the data structure and do an infix print (O(n)) sorting

Comment: just to clear up something, the word "merge" is related to how the algorithm works internally, it has nothing to do with receiving 2 lists and merging them sorted as the question describes

Answer (score 2):

Clearly the best thing to do is to copy the contents of N into the free space in the N+M array and quicksort the N+M array.

By doing 2 quicksorts and then a merge sort you are just making the entire operation less efficient.

Here is a mental exercise, if you had to sort an array of length M, would you split it into 2 arrays, M1 and M2, sort each and then merge sort them together? No. If you did that you would just be limiting information available to each call of quicksort, slowing down the process.

So why would you keep your two starting arrays separate?

Comment: +1, as it's far more direct and hassle free. Although, since it's homework, it's probably not what is being looked for, but seems like this is what should be done in general.

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing in a second array, than you are using extra space, but you can minimize that by helping the GC like this:

- join both arrays in a second array
- set both previous variables to null so they are eligible to be garbage collected
- sort the second array, `Arrays.sort(...)` - **O(n log(n))**

Look at the javadoc for this method:

```
/**
  * Sorts the specified array into ascending numerical order.
  *
  * <p>Implementation note: The sorting algorithm is a Dual-Pivot Quicksort
  * by Vladimir Yaroslavskiy, Jon Bentley, and Joshua Bloch. This algorithm
  * offers O(n log(n)) performance on many data sets that cause other
  * quicksorts to degrade to quadratic performance, and is typically
  * faster than traditional (one-pivot) Quicksort implementations.
  *
  * @param a the array to be sorted
  */
  public static void sort(int[] a) {
```

Answer (score 0):

If i wanted to guarantee also the O(n*log(n)) behaviour, I would use modified version of [Heapsort](http://en.algoritmy.net/article/39807/Heapsort), which would use the both arrays as a base for the the heap, and would store the sorted data in the additional part of the array.

This also might be faster than two Quicksorts, because it does not require the additional merge operation. Also Quicksort is terribly slow, when small arrays are being sorted (the size of the problem is not mentioned the the setting of the problem).

Answer (score 0):

Let's call the smaller array the N array and the other one the M array.  I'm assuming the elements of the M array are initially in locations 0 through m-1.  Sort both arrays using your favorite technique, which may depend on other criteria such as stability or limiting worst-case behavior.

```
if min(N) > max(M)
   copy N's elements over starting at location m [O(n) time]   
else
   move M's elements to the end of the M array (last down to first) [O(m) time]   
   if min(M) > max(N)
      copy N's elements over starting at location 0 [O(n) time for the copy]
   else
      perform classic merge: min of remaining m's and n's gets migrated
      to next available space in M [O(min(m,n) time]
```

Overall this is dominated by the initial sorting time, the merge phase is all linear.  Migrating the m's to the end of the M array guarantees no space collisions, so you don't need extra side storage as per your specification.